# Click on Application MainWindow from Taskbar is not showing (Converted Modeless dialog to Modal)

Tags: mfc

My MFC application is a MDI application. and I have a MFC Extension dll, MFC Extension dll will launch the child dialog on top of the MFC MDI application. like as below

```
CMyDialog  pDisplayGlobal = new CMyDialog(IDD_DISPLAY, NULL);    
pDisplayGlobal->Create(IDD_DISPLAY, AfxGetApp()->m_pMainWnd);
pDisplayGlobal->ShowWindow(SW_NORMAL);
```

Note : Kindly let me know if I am doing anything wrong in above code.

Problem:
I have launched my MFC mdi application and child modeless dialog as well. Modeless dialog always on top of parent window only (as per the above code)

```
Step1) I have opened other four different applications (Which means my MFC application is behind  these four applications)
Step2) I clicked on my MFC application from the Taskbar it’s not showing the main application window. which means it didnt come in front its still in step1 stage only
Step3) To see My MFC application I have to minimize all the four applications
```

That’s the problem, kindly somebody give me some code snippet as a solution.

Thanks in advance.

Comment: It's not clear what you are asking. This code will not compile: `CDialog  pDisplayGlobal = new CDialog(IDD_DISPLAY, NULL);` but that's probably copy/paste error. You don't show the location of the code, if it's in `CMyWinApp` or somewhere else. It's not clear why you want to create a child dialog. Is this supposed to be a dialog based application?

Comment: Hi Barmak, corrected the mistake, I have created the CDialog object of derived class not the CDialog. Please see the code in above.

Comment: `CDialog` was fine. You didn't correct any mistakes and you didn't answer any of my questions. Please read this http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve Variafiable example: `CMyWinApp::InitInstance() { CDialog dlg(IDD_X); dlg.DoModal(); ...}`

Comment: My MFC  application is a MDI application. and

I have a MFC Extension dll, MFC Extension dll will launch the child dialog on top of the MFC MDI application. 

till my child dialog closes, I may not restoring the MFC application from the taskbar click as above mentioned steps in my first thread.

Kindly do me the favour by providing some solution to this issue.

Answer (score 0):

To run a dialog from another program you can do the following

in DLL:

```
CDialog *g_dlg;
void dll_foo()
{
    g_dlg = new CDialog;
    g_dlg->Create(IDD_DIALOG1);
    g_dlg->ShowWindow(SW_SHOWNORMAL);
}
```

in main app:

```
BOOL CMyWinApp::InitInstance()
{
    //...
    frame->ShowWindow(SW_SHOWNORMAL);
    frame->UpdateWindow();
    dll_foo();
    return TRUE;
}
```